# How to populate a search template parameter from a query string parameters in the SumoLogic user interface

Tags: sumologic

Using the [SumoLogic Search Templates](https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Get-Started-with-Search/How-to-Build-a-Search/Search-Templates) with the [tourl](https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Search-Query-Language/Search-Operators/tourl) operator combined with the ability to [Use_a_URL_to_Run_a_Search](https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Get-Started-with-Search/How-to-Build-a-Search/Use_a_URL_to_Run_a_Search)

I would like to launch a search that sets the search parameters via query string arguments. I've been unable to find documentation on this ability, and it doesn't seem supported.

It seems my only option would be to create something custom that uses the API directly to get the desired behavior.

Anyone else tried this or have advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly what you are asking for but have you considered just using the share url feature?  This properly populates parameters prefilled and is much easier to construct to boot.

https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Get-Started-with-Search/Search-Basics/Share-a-Link-to-a-Search

Comment: It's a good thought, I'll see if there is a way to generate the share link at runtime, it could work, I don't care if they are human readable, just if I can generate a link to another parametrized search/dashboard. I'll let you know what I find when I can back to this. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: in a round about way this does work, however it has some challenges. The share link with the params options only seems to be supported on the Dashboards, but not on shareable searchers. What I want is a link generated in a report on a dashboard report, so that when I click on it, it goes to another shared search. I was able to get this to work by adding an intermediary dashboard, and then clicking the 'go to search' link in the dashboard panel.